# How to resolve auto generated classes in Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, psr-4

In a Symfony3 project, which is using psr 4, I am storing configuration data by auto generating a php class in the 'var/cache/dev' folder.

Here is a simplified copy of the generated file:

```
<?php

use Project\Bundle\Metadata\AbstractMetadata;

class LocalizedMetadata extends AbstractMetadata
{
    protected function populate ()
    {
    }
}
```

I know I can `include` or `require` the file, but the 'dev' directory changes between development and production, and I use the class in several places. Also, I'm hoping to use this bundle in other projects, so I don't want to hard code anything outside of the bundle. How are these files usually loaded? Is there anything within the Symfony core to assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any classes created in the 'dev' directory cannot be auto loaded, at least not without configuring files outside of the bundle (eg. composer.yml).

I took a look into how Symfony manages it's router files, and the solution was actually quite simple.

I made a manager class which can be called from anywhere in the code. This class contains a method which returns an instance of the class in the cache folder.

```
public function getLocalizedRoutes ()
{
    if ( null !== $this->localizedRoutes ) {
        return $this->localizedRoutes;
    }

    $cache = $this->getConfigCacheFactory()->cache(
        $this->options['cache_dir'].'/'.CachingMetadata::CACHE_FILE,
        function (ConfigCacheInterface $cache) {
            $content = CachingMetadata::getInstance()->dump();
            $cache->write($content);
        }
    );

    require_once $cache->getPath();

    return $this->localizedRoutes = LocalizedMetadata::getInstance();
}
```

It uses Symfony's built in `ConfigCache` class, simply because it handles the file write and file permissions. Also, it will call the closure if the file doesn't exist. In this case the closure calls into the class which handles the loading of data and converting it into PHP code. The cache file is then loaded with `require_once` and an instance of `LocalizedMetadata`, which is the cached class name, is returned.

The above method can be modified to also pass resource files to ConfigCache, that way if one of your files is modified, the cache will be rewritten. In my case it wasn't required.

Making this work with a cache warmer simply requires a call to the above method:

```
class RouteCacheWarmer implements CacheWarmerInterface
{
    private $_manager;

    public function __construct ( LocaleManager $manager )
    {
        $this->_manager = $manager;
    }

    public function isOptional ()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function warmUp ( $cacheDir )
    {
        $this->_manager->getLocalizedRoutes();
    }
}
```

I would also like to note, it's possible to use namespaces within the cache file.